# Time from difference of two Date/Time fields

Tags: formula-field

I want to get time in hours from the difference of two Date/Time fields.
But currently for two Times such as 12 pm and 1 pm ,formula field  is returning .04 hours .
How is it getting calculated?

Comment: Are you trying in formula or in Apex

Comment: Formula field .

Comment: So I read that its getting calculated like : For example, if the difference between two Date/Time values is 5.52, that means the two values are separated by five days, 12 hours (0.5 of a day), and 28 minutes (0.02 of a day). -- Any way I can get the numeric difference of the time ?

Comment: I am not sure exact solution, work around will be calculating the field again after return the result

Comment: To get the result in hours, multiply by 24. For minutes, 1440 (60*24).

Comment: a google search "salesforce calculate difference between two datetimes" yields a plethora of results